# About maximization a product of functions

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I want to maximize a function of the form $f(x)=f_1(x)f_2(x)$ where $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are differentiable and positive functions and are defined on the interval $(x_1,x_2)$. Further, I know the following about the functions

1- The function $f_1(x)$ strictly increases in the interval $x_1\leq x \leq a$ and it strictly decreases over the interval $a\leq x \leq x_2$.

2- The function $f_2(x)$ strictly increases in the interval $x_1\leq x \leq b$ and it strictly decreases over the interval $b \leq x \leq x_2$.

So if I want to maximize the function $f(x)$ then can I take the derivative of $f(x)$ and put it equal to zero?

My Current Understanding:

I think if the functions $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are concave then the properties defined above are true for concave functions and we can take the derivative of $f(x)$ to get the maxima of the function $f(x)$. However, in my problem the functions $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are not concave (since the second derivative condition does not hold). So I am confused about how to maximize the function $f(x)$? Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To take derivatives, at the very least you need your functions to be differentiable, but I don't see that among the given properties.

Comment: @zipirovich thank you for your comment. I have added that the functions are differentiable. Can we say something about it now?

Comment: In general, you want to look at all the stationary points (points at which $f^{'}(x) = 0$) or boundary points ($x = x_1$ or $x = x_2$) as candidates for maxima. Is your question whether you need to consider the boundary points at all? In your particular case, if $a$ and $b$ are in the open interval $(x_1, x_2)$, then you do not need to consider the boundary points. I do not understand your comments about concavity.